# Angular - Dynamically Create Component From Service

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular app, and I want to create a toastr like service where I can show different kinds of predefined modals (confirmation, contact us etc..) from different places in my app.
For example: 
I have a ConfirmBackButtonBehaviorGuard which is bound to the route canDeactivate behavior.
From this guard, I want to open a modal using a service like:

```js
const promise = modalsService.openConfirmDialog('Are you sure', 'Leaving this page without saving....', 'Yes Take Me Out', 'Stay Here' );
var result = await promise();
...
```

The problem is that I need to access some viewContainerRef in order to dynamically create the modal. 
I thought about adding some container into the app.component, but I'm not sure how to access it from (if it is even possible) from a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use **CompnentFactoryResolver** class to achieve similar behavior. The class *resolveComponentFactory* method dynamically resolves component which you pass in as a parameter. It also allows you to pass data to your dynamic component by utilizing injection tokens, listen (subscribe) to **close** action and pull results from dialog.

Here is an example of what the api might look like once implemented:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-host-modal',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppHostModal {
  constructor(public modalService: ModalService) {}

  onConfirmCancel(): void {
    this.modalService.open(FancyPopupComponent, {
      data: { message: 'Are you sure?' },
    });
  }

}
```

This [article](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components/) provides details on how to implement this.

Besides custom implementation, you can use [CDK overlays](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview).

Another and the easiest option is to use [material dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

Comment: Thank you very much, your link really helped me understand this and more